# Two databases in one DataContext with relations between databases

Tags: c#, mysql, database, entity-framework

I want to have one common database where are tables like Users, Employees and so on, and second database where I store some data (for example company shopping list) and I want to use Users from common database table as foreign keys in the second database's tables.

I want it like this to avoid duplication of Users table in every database that I create for different solutions. Then I have same list of users for different solutions and I dont need to update Users in every database.

Comment: I am surprise that this(foreign keys to other dbs) is possible in MySQL :) on database level. There are some scenarios(backup db, restore) where that brings problems(referential integrity) in e.g. SQL Server. So I would be surprised, if EF did support that out of the box (Microsoft, you know...loves SQL Server). Maybe you can do it manually.